# How do you convert a cell value in a DataGridView into a integer if it's an integer, and a string when it's a string?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, datagridview

I have a DataGridview called "dgvDynamic" which displays data from a MS Access DB into a DataGridView. I want to show the value of the selected cell, into a textbox called "txtSelectedCell".

However, it will only show data of a string datatype in the textbox, not integers. How can I display both strings and integers in the textbox? Thank you. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub dgvDynamic_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvDynamic.CellContentClick

        txtSelectedCell.Text = dgvDynamic.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString

End Sub
```

Comment: Because you're using the wrong event... Use the cell click event and then `txtSelectedCell.Text = dgvDynamic.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()`

Comment: @Codexer what event should I be using then? Thanks.

Comment: @Codexer thanks fixed it!!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I used the wrong event. Instead of using the "CellContent" event I should've used the "ClickEvent" and then changing the statement

From:
 `txtSelectedCell.Text = dgvDynamic.SelectedCells(0).Value.ToString`

To: `txtSelectedCell.Text = dgvDynamic.CurrentCell.Value.ToString()`

Thanks @Codex for solving the problem for me.

Comment: If what you want to do is track the value of the `CurrentCell` then the logical event to handle is `CurrentCellChanged`. It doesn't make sense to handle anything to do with clicking because it's possible to change the current cell without using the mouse.  For the record, `CellContentClick` is for when you want to know that something inside the cell, e.g. button, check box or link, is clicked.